# sending a generic class object to a generic method (java)

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter, generic-method

I have a class named `InstanceClass` as follows:

```
package trials;

public class InstanceClass<T>  {

    private T num;

    public void calculate() {
        System.out.printf("%s", num);
    }
    public T getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public void setNum(T num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public InstanceClass(T num) {
        super();
        this.num = num;
    }
}
```

and `Trial` class in which the main method located as follows:

```
package trials;

public class TrialClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        InstanceClass<Integer> my=new InstanceClass<>(2);
        InstanceClass<InstanceClass<Integer>> x=new InstanceClass<>(my);
        prt(x.getNum());
    }
    
    public static <T extends InstanceClass<Integer>> void prt(T q) {
        System.out.printf("%s%n",q.getNum());
        q.calculate();
    }
}
```

So, I want to know why can't we simply use <T> instead of <T extends InstanceClass<Integer>> in the method prt's declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change

```
public static <T extends InstanceClass<Integer>> void prt(T q)
```

to

```
public static <T> void prt(T q)
```

the compiler wouldn't know that the type parameter `T` must be an `InstanceClass`, and therefore it wouldn't know that it has `getNum()` and `calculate()` methods, which you are trying to call from `prt`.

In fact, the compiler would allow you to pass to the `prt` method any argument, including instances of classes unrelated to `InstanceClass`, which don't have the methods you are trying to call inside `prt`.